# PHP/JavaScript - Ping Test

Tags: php, jquery, ping

Is there any way that I can allow a user to ping a test IP that will go from

User --> Server --> Their Actual Ping Not The Servers

I know you can ping using PHP, but PHP can't execute anything from the clients side.

jQuery maybe?

Thanks for any tips or suggestions.

Comment: You may just measre the time to download a 1byte static file from the server, given it's not overloaded and it's done just after page loading, using HTTP/1.1 persistent connection, you might be pretty close to ping time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaScript isn't capable of performing an ICMP Echo request which is use to ping a server.

The closest alternative is to make an HTTP request using the `XMLHttpRequest` or `Image` object and measure the time taken; of course, the time taken for that is the combination of DNS lookup, TCP handshake, sending headers, server processing and receiving the response.

I should note that after the first "ping" the subsequent requests are probably more accurate.